# Invitation letter for self-funded UK standard visa application

Tags: visas, uk

I’m going to apply for a UK standard tourist visa along with my wife and kid. I have enough savings to fund my 10-days visit. I'm planning to attach an invitation letter from a friend residing in the UK, and we'll be staying at his house. He'll accommodate us but all other expenses I'll take care of myself.

So, besides the invitation letter, what other documents should he send me for my tourist visa application? Is it a good idea to attach an invitation letter from a not-so-close friend? Does he need to attach his financial statements to invite me when I have enough funds to support our trip?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having an invitation letter from the friend you will stay with in the UK is certainly helpful. If he lives in council housing then he will also need to send you proof that he is allowed to have overnight guests in his flat. This usually is [a letter from the estate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48470/3221) but can also be a copy of the tenancy agreement if it grants such permission.

You do not really need to have an invitation letter from anyone else.

Comment: You might wish to suggest that OP also reviews this info [UK visa for my child refused as ECO could not be satisfied that their welfare would be taken care of (V4.11 V4.12](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109423/uk-visa-for-my-child-refused-as-eco-could-not-be-satisfied-that-their-welfare-wo/109441#109441) , as the bar is significantly higher when a minor child is involved.